# Slack for civicrm?

Tags: discussion

I think we can have a slack org setup for civicrm. This will not allow only developers to communicate better bet also help in communications for GSOC students. I understand while the same can be done via IRC too, but slack provide much better tracking bots, etc. Its free (for last 10000 messages).

PS: Not sure whether this is the right place to post.

Comment: Isn't there already a chatroom for CivicCRM on Stack Exchange chat?

Comment: We use mattermost now, the same is hosted at https://chat.civicrm.org

Comment: Right. I'm wondering why y'all opted to use something besides the chat that's already connected to the Q&A software though.

Comment: MatterMost offers a lot more integration for software builders, and is a tool we can "own". Stack Exchange is a good tool for community Q&A, but not the tool we chose as a platform for chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using an opensource product similar to Slack called MatterMost. Please signup at [https://chat.civicrm.org](http://chat.civicrm.org).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (for now). MatterMost at https://chat.civicrm.org/ seems to have taken off just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

What would be the benefit over IRC?

Comment: The idea is to have different channels. For example a lot of discussion on GSoC can happen on an email, but a private/public channel works great for too for general/mentor discussions.